# Using Kubernetes Downward Api while using configmap and envFrom configMapRef

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I'm using both env and envFrom in my k8s deployment manifest as below.

```
envFrom:
  - configMapRef:
      name: env
env:
  - name: POD_NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

I know I can inject env using K8s downward api using env as below.

```
env:
  - name: POD_NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  - name: SOME_ENDPOINT
    value: mysvc.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
```

However, when I try to create env using ConfigMap, as below, I am not getting intended variable.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env
data:
  SOME_ENDPOINT: mysvc.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
```

The expected result when I run printenv inside the container is `SOME_ENDPOINT` having `mysvc.myns.svc.cluster.local` value, but the result is `SOME_ENDPOINT` having value of `mysvc.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local` itself.

Any solutions on injecting env using configmap with Downward Api?

Thanks!

Comment: Although not sure if variables can be dereferenced that way, can you try switching parentheses to brackets? e.g. `mysvc.${POD_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local`